# VUE cannot update variable when API response

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to update {{info}} value when the API is response.
But I don't know why there could be console log the response but cannot update the variable.
Any mistake I have make?

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>{{info}}</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    const { reactive,createApp, ref } = Vue;
    const app = {
         setup(){
            info="waiting......";
            axios
            .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                    .then(response => (this.info = response))
                    .then(response => (console.log(response)));
            return {info};
        }
    }
    const myVue = Vue.createApp(app).mount("#app");

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example. If you want to use the composition API you have to make `info` a reactive variable with `ref` or `reactive`.

in this case you have to assign the new data to your reactive variable with the `.value` notation: `info.value = data`

### composition API

```js
const { createApp, onMounted, ref } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    let info = ref('warning...')
    
    onMounted(() => {
      fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          info.value = data
        });
    })

    return {
      info
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{info}}</p>
</div>
```

### options API

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      info: 'warning...'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
   fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.info = data
    });
  }
}).mount('#options-api')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="options-api">
  <p>{{ info }}</p>
</div>
```

> console log the response but cannot update the variable

you have mixed the style from the composition API with the options API.

your code `this.info = response` will work with the options API (see my second example.) if you want to use the composition API you have to write `info.value = response` (see my first example).

note: I use the mounted hook only for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

one of workaround, using vue 2........

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>{{info}}</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare a reactive variable via "reactive" in Vue3.
such as:

```
enter code hereconst app = {
     setup(){
        // if your request return a value. otherwise, use as below
        // let info = reactive({});
        let info = ref("waiting......");
        axios
        .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                .then(response => (this.info = response))
                .then(response => (console.log(response)));
        return {info};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [composition API documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref), you need to use `ref`.

I.e. your code should be

```
const info=ref("waiting......");
```

Otherwise, it is just a normal JavaScript variable, and the "reactive magic" of Vue which re-renders the view does not kick in when you change the value. Please note that in some contexts, Vue does automatically make objects reactive, e. g. for `data` and `props` when you use the normal components syntax. But for teh composition API, you have to take care of that yourself.